# Why I get NaN out after sapply

Tags: r, sapply

I have data which looks like:

```
datas <- as.matrix(rnorm(100, mean=90, sd=5))
```

Then, I tried to transform with:

```
sapply(datas, function(x) {(x-min(x))/((max(x)-min(x)))})
```

I get NaN.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably division by zero. You could try `{(x-min(datas))/((max(x=datas)-min(datas)))})`

Comment: No need to use `sapply`. You could do: `(datas - min(datas)) / diff(range(datas))`

Comment: How about if I would like to apply this function per column? I mean, min and max per column will be different.

Comment: you're getting nan because when you sapply over a matrix, you are looping over individual elements, so `max(x) - min(x)` will be 0 in every case. you could loop over a data frame, eg, `sapply(data.frame(datas), ...` which would work for this example or a multi column matrix

Comment: If you want to iterate over columns look at `apply()` with `MARGIN = 2`.

Comment: To troubleshoot problems like this (where `sapply` is operating on one datum at a time), I suggest learning how to use `browser()` (one good ref: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html#browser). If you do `sapply(datas, function(x) { browser(); (x-min(x))/((max(x)-min(x))); })`, your prompt will change to `Browse[2]>` and you will be "inside" the anon-func. If you now look at `x`, you'll see that it's a single value, and it should be clearer. Debugging 1-letter commands: `n`ext line/expression, `c`ontinue (leave debugger, continue evaluation), `s`tep into an expr, and `Q`uit immediately.